# integrate $\tan^{-1}(x)/x$ using power series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

$$
\int \frac{\tan^{-1} (x)}{x} \, dx
$$

Having trouble finding a power series representation of this. This is what I have so far but the math software telling me it's incorrect.

$$
C+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n}
$$

Comment: That is the series for arctan.  Now divide by $x$ and then integrate.

Comment: @GEdgar divided by x still wrong

Comment: Now integrate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series treatment is$$\begin{align}\arctan x&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\\\implies\frac{\arctan x}{x}&=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n}\\\implies\int\frac{\arctan x}{x}&=C+\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}x^{2n+1}.\end{align}$$

Comment: interesting i forgot the square on the bottom, thats why, thanks homie, the other dude told me i was right when I was wrong